# I just started python and I need help making math questions in python

Tags: python

I just started coding python then maybe changing to java or c++ but for now on python. I am trying to make a simple math question (that's kinda random), and I couldn't figure out how to do this:

```
import sys

print("---[WELCOME TO MATH TEST]---")
print("----------------------------")
print("")
name = input("Enter your Username:  ")
print("Good Job!")
code = input("Now Enter your Password:  ")
print("You are Ready to go Now!")
print("Let's Start With the Game:")
q1 = input("54 + 120 =   ")

q1 = 174

if q1 == 174:
    print("Correct! Next question..")

else:
    print("Wrong..")

q2 = input("630+ 350 =   ")

q2 = 980

if q2 == 980:
    print("Correct!")

else:
    print("Wrong..")
    sys.exit()
```

When I put answer it always says correct, even if it's completely wrong. but I only want the number that is q1 = 980 is the one that is always correct and anything else is wrong..

Comment: The result of `input("630+ 350 =   ")` is a string, so `'980' == 980` will be always false (but `int('980') == 980` will be true).

Comment: @Enzo Did you notice that the answer will always be correct instead of false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

q1 = input("54 + 120 =   ")

In the above code, you are taking the value from the user using input func.

But in the very next line , 
q1 = 174

you are assigning the value of q1 to be 174.

As a result, you are always getting a correct output.

Try to remove the variable assignment after you take the input from the user.

Also, the data type of input function is always a string. You can change it to int by,
q1 = int(input("54 + 120 =   "))

If you do this then your if statement will not throw an error.

So the final code looks like this,

```
enter code hereprint("---[WELCOME TO MATH TEST]---")
print("----------------------------")
print("")
name = input("Enter your Username:  ")
print("Good Job!")
code = input("Now Enter your Password:  ")
print("You are Ready to go Now!")
print("Let's Start With the Game:")
q1 = int(input("54 + 120 =   "))

if q1 == 174:
    print("Correct! Next question..")

else:
    print("Wrong..")

q2 = int(input("630+ 350 =   "))

if q2 == 980:
    print("Correct!")

else:
    print("Wrong..")
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code:

```
q2 = input("630+ 350 =   ")

q2 = 980

if q2 == 980:
    print("Correct!")
```

after the user input a number, you overwrite with 980, making it always correct.

To correct that:

```
q2 = int(input("630+ 350 =   "))

q3 = 980

if q2 == q3:
    print("Correct!")
```

Here my way for the whole program:

```
from random import randint

num1 = randint(100,1000)
num2 = randint(100,1000)
ans = input(f"{num1} + {num2} = ")
if int(ans) == num1 + num2:
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Wrong...")
```

Output:

```
633 + 658 = 1291
Correct!
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove 'q1 = 174' and 'q2 = 980'. And use int function to convert string to int.
Here is the changed code.

```
print("---[WELCOME TO MATH TEST]---")
print("----------------------------")
print("")
name = input("Enter your Username:  ")
print("Good Job!")
code = input("Now Enter your Password:  ")
print("You are Ready to go Now!")
print("Let's Start With the Game:")
q1 = input("54 + 120 =   ")

# q1 = 174

if int(q1) == 174:
    print("Correct! Next question..")

else:
    print("Wrong..")

q2 = input("630+ 350 =   ")

# q2 = 980

if int(q2) == 980:
    print("Correct!")

else:
    print("Wrong..")
    sys.exit()
```